# HTML unit driver with selenium not click the button

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, automated-tests, htmlunit-driver

I want to click a element with onclick tag in html unit driver. But it didn't work.

[Page source:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q6F4.png)

I tried following method.

1. click method;

   public HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME, true);
   driver.get(appURL);
   WebElement dripBoxbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='idp-image']/.."));
           dripBoxbutton.click();
2. Submit method;

   ```
   public HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME, true);
   driver.get(appURL);
           WebElement dripBoxbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='idp-image']/.."));
                   dripBoxbutton.submit();
   ```

   Error when using submit button:

   Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import org.openqa.selenium.By; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org. . . . '' : Method Invocation dripBoxbutton.submit : at Line: 48 : in file: inline evaluation of:`import org.openqa.selenium.By; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org. . . . '' : dripBoxbutton .submit ( )

   Target exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    in inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.By; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org. . . . '' at line number 48

   Response headers:

   3. Key release

      import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
       public HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME, true);
          driver.get(appURL);
      WebElement dripBoxbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='idp-image']/.."));
      dripBoxbutton.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Error when using kye release:

Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import org.openqa.selenium.By; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org. . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method sendKeys( org.openqa.selenium.Keys ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement' : at Line: 49 : in file: inline evaluation of:`import org.openqa.selenium.By; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org. . . . '' : dripBoxbutton .sendKeys ( Keys .ENTER ) 
 in inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.By; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org. . . . '' at line number 49

```
Response headers:
```

4. action method;

   ```
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
       public HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME, true);
       driver.get(appURL);
       WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='idp-image']/.."));
               Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
               builder.moveToElement(webElement).click(webElement);
   ```

   builder.perform();

How to find a way to click the button in Html unit driver.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting indicates a syntax problem, you can get more informative stacktrace by putting your code into [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

```
try {
    //your code here
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Failure in script", ex);
}
```

This way you will be able to see the root cause of your problem in *jmeter.log* file.

In particular your case my expectation is that you're using some function which is not supported by [Beanshell](http://beanshell.org/) language. You can try switching to `Groovy` - most probably it will automatically resolve your issue:

[image: JMeter WebDriver Groovy]

Moreover, according to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) you should be using Groovy for any scripting tasks in JMeter mainly because [Groovy has better performance than other JMeter scripting options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).